# Pandas dataframe - filter list of tuples

Tags: python, pandas

I'm attempting to modify a dataframe which contains a list of tuples within it's column values such that if a sequence of 'off' and 'on' is encountered for a sequence of tuples then they are removed from the dataframe.

Here is the dataframe prior to processing :

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

array = np.array([[1, [('on',1),('off',1),('off',1),('on',1)]], [2,[('off',1),('on',1),('on',1),('off',1)]]])
index_values = ['first', 'second']
column_values = ['id', 'l']
df = pd.DataFrame(data = array, 
                  index = index_values, 
                  columns = column_values)
```

which renders :

[image]

I'm attempting to produce this dataframe :

[image]

Here is my attempt :

```
updated_col = []
for d in df['l'] : 
    for index, value in enumerate(d) : 
        if len(value) == index : 
            break 
        elif value[index] == 'off' and value[index + 1] == 'on' : 
            updated_col.append(value)
```

The variable `updated_col` is empty. Cana lambda be used to process over the column and remove values where a sequence of `off` and `on` are found ?

Edit :

Custom pairwise function  :

this seems to do the trick  :

```
import itertools
def pairwise(x) : 
    return list(itertools.combinations(x, 2))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from itertools import pairwise
# Or (Depending on python version)
from more_itertools import pairwise

df.l = df.l.apply(lambda v: [x for x in pairwise(v)
                             if x == (('on', 1), ('off', 1))][0]).map(list)
```

Output:

```
       id                    l
first   1  [(on, 1), (off, 1)]
second  2  [(on, 1), (off, 1)]
```

Comment: thanks, is there an alternative for pairwise ? trying to use returns 'ImportError: cannot import name 'pairwise' from 'itertools' (unknown location)'

Comment: please see update, does the custom function look correct ?

Comment: your solution does not work if there are multiple on, off, e.g : array = np.array([[1, [('on',1),('off',1),('off',1),('on',1)]], [2,[('off',1),('on',1),('on',1),('off',1),('on',1),('off',1),('on',1),('off',1)]]])

Answer (score 0):

If you want the unique values in each row, you can use `set` to update your dataframe

```
for i in range(df.shape[0]):
    df['l'][i] = set(df['l'][i])
```

If you want to remove the duplicates in the sequence, you can use the `itertools` package like this:

```
from itertools import groupby
for i in range(df.shape[0]):
    list_=[]
    for k, c in groupby(df['l'][i]):
        list_.append(k)
    
    df['l'][i] = list_
```